# Swift 4: Filtering an array of structures using UISearchController

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

i want to filter an array of structures were:

```
var fullProveedoresFiltrados:[MCCollectionServicess]?
```

my struct is:

```
struct MCServices: Decodable {
    var ciudad: String?
    var code: String?
    var name: String?
    var commission: String?
    var typeCommission: String?
    var balance: Bool?
    var typeService: String?
    var reference: String?
    var status: String?
    var image: String?
    var mcPlace : String?
    var provisioningCommission:String?
}

struct MCCollectionServicess: Decodable {
    var title: String?
    var data: [MCServices]?
}
```

i want to get only one item filtering by data.name and all section filtering by title, but my filter return all section when i try to get only a item by name.

my search:

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        
        guard let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
        
        fullProveedoresFiltrados = fullProveedores!.filter({ proveedor -> Bool in
            
            for item in 0..<proveedor.data!.count {

                if proveedor.data![item].name!.forSortingTarjeta.lowercased().localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText.lowercased().forSortingTarjeta) {
                    return proveedor.data![item].name!.forSortingTarjeta.lowercased().localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText.lowercased().forSortingTarjeta)
                }

            }
            
            return proveedor.title!.forSortingTarjeta.lowercased().localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText.lowercased().forSortingTarjeta)
             
        })
        
        changeButton.isHidden = fullProveedoresFiltrados!.count != 0 ? false : true
        noFoundResult.isHidden = fullProveedoresFiltrados!.count != 0 ? true : false
        
        collectionView.reloadData()
        
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but why is everything optional? Declare all objects which you force unwrap anyway as non-optional, for example `var fullProveedoresFiltrados = [MCCollectionServicess]()`

Comment: Maybe you could add some sample data and an example search and the expected result